# Criar função para alterar um dado na tabela de base de dados

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, array

Bom dia, estou a fazer uma função para puder alterar um dado numa tabela da base de dados. Isto é, tenho 4 dados registados na minha tabela de base de dados em que o main é 'sim', ao registar um quinto dado, o segundo dado mais antigo tem de passar para 'não' no main.

```
public function removeMain(){
        $news = News::Where('main' == 'Sim')->get();
        if(count($news) == 4){
            $news = News::Where('id','=', $news[2]->id)->first();
            $news->main = 'Não';
        }
    }
```

O código que já tenho é este mas continua sem me alterar o dado no main. Será que alguem me pode dar uma ajuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentação Laravel:

```
$flight = App\Flight::find(1);

$flight->name = 'New Flight Name';

$flight->save();
```

Ou seja, você busca o dado, altera o que precisar e deve salva-lo após a alteração.

No seu caso, creio que resolverá apenas adicionando `$news->save()` após `$news->main = 'Não';`.

Espero que ajude!

Ref.: [Update Eloquent - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#updates)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!